# Vue.js - Reactivity component, not always re-rendering

Tags: javascript, charts, vue.js, vuejs2

I face a problem of reactivity for two components `line-chart` and `bar-chart`

When I'm changing the checkbox value link to `v-model="formChart.type` the component `line-chart` and `bar-chart` are automatically re-rendered.

**BUT** when I'm clicking on the `button` that triggers the function `submitForm` and then `generateChart()` and `resetTypeChart()` those components are not re-rendered.

The `mounted()` function is not triggered.

I really don't get why this is happening since I'm reseting both the `type` and `show`.... I tried with or without the `Vue.set` nothing has changed.

**The code does go into the `resetTypeChart()` function**

---

#### Components not always re-rendering

```
  <div class="chart-container">
      <line-chart v-if="formChart.type === 'line_chart' && formChart.show" :chartData="dataChart" ref="lineChart"></line-chart>
      <bar-chart v-if="formChart.type === 'bar_chart' && formChart.show" :chartData="dataChart" ref="barChart"></bar-chart>
  </div>
```

#### Checkbox to change the type of chart

```
<el-radio-group size="small" v-model="formChart.type">
     <el-radio-button label="line_chart"> Line Chart </el-radio-button>
     <el-radio-button label="bar_chart"> Bar Chart </el-radio-button>
</el-radio-group>
```

#### Button that generates the chart

```
<el-button type="primary" size="large"@click="submitForm('formChart')">Generate</el-button>

submitForm(formName) {
   this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
      this.generateChart();
      this.resetTypeChart();
   } 
});
```

#### Function that reset the chart (it is a try)

```
resetTypeChart () {
  const saveType = this.formChart.type;
  this.formChart.type = '';
  this.formChart.show = false;
  Vue.set(this.formChart, 'type', saveType);
  this.formChart.type = saveType;
  this.formChart.show = true;
 }
```

#### JSFIDDLE

- Switch to `Bar Chart` and the component is generated
- Click on `Generate` while still being on the same radio button. Nothing is shown.

https://jsfiddle.net/rd3ahxp8/3/

Comment: You're not really changing anything in `resetTypeChart`. It's not as if Vue runs off and does anything between the time you set show to false and back to true. After the function is complete, *then* it will see if it needs to do something and, in this case, I don't think it will see anthing changed. Can you make a working example where we can see the issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: I will try to make a example but it won't be easy ... How would you explain that changing the checkbox so the `formChart.type` re-render the component when it is linked to `v-model` but not when I'm doing `this.formChart.type = ''` and then ` this.formChart.type = ''bar_chart"`

Comment: Because DOM updates happen [asynchronously](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue). If you just click the radio button, then Vue has time for the next asynchronous DOM update to run. But an update is not going to run in the middle of the execution of your method.

Comment: I created a `jsfiddle` simpler that I expected. If you switch the `radio button` it will show `bar chart generated` if you click on the generate it won't display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you do not see an alert when you click the generate button is because Vue has decided that nothing has really changed, so it doesn't need to update the DOM. As I was saying in the comments above, Vue DOM updates happen asynchronously, which means that Vue is not going to check to see if anything has changed until *after* your method is complete. When your method is *complete*, nothing in your state has really changed; you set it to some value, and then set it right back to the *original* value.

To demonstrate [I modified your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd3ahxp8/5/) and introduced a time delay between the time you clear the values and the time you set them back. You can see, in *this* case, Vue has time to check to see that the values have changed and then they are changed *back*, you get your message.

```
generateChart : function () {
    alert('generate')
    const saveType = this.formChart.type;
    this.formChart.type = '';
    this.formChart.show = false;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.formChart.type = saveType;
      this.formChart.show = true;

    }, 1000)
}
```

I think what *should* be triggering an update in your case is some change to `dataChart`. When that value changes, your Vue *should* re-render. You don't show, however, that it ever changes. Right now, if the data hasn't changed, and you don't want the user to see a *different* chart (because you're setting it back to the same value), why re-render at all?

In order to get your chart to re-render when the chartData changes, you should watch the chartData property in your components. Here is a complete example of how I might do this.

```
const ChartBase = {
  props: ["chartData"],
  methods:{
    showChart(){
      this.renderChart({
        labels: this.chartData.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: this.chartData.data
          }
        ]
      }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
    }
  },
  mounted : function () {
    this.showChart()
    this.$watch("chartData.data", this.showChart)
  },
}

Vue.component('bar-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
  mixins: [ChartBase]
});

Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mixins:[ChartBase]
});

var Main = {
  data () {
    return {
      formChart : {
        type : 'line_chart',
        show : false,
      },
      chartData:{
        labels:['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
      }
    };
  },
  methods : {
    generateChart : function () {
      const newChartData = [...this.chartData.data.reverse()] 
      this.chartData.data = newChartData
    }
  },
}
```

And [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd3ahxp8/8/) showing the charts changing when the `generate` button is clicked.

Comment: Isn't risky to rely on a `setTimeout` ? What about `$nextTick` ?

Comment: @Leo I'm not suggesting it as a solution to your problem; I'm trying to demonstrate why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing. I think what should *really* trigger your re-render should be a change to `dataChart`.

Comment: `dataChart` is modified in the `generateChart()` What would be your approach taking into account I also need to consider the `type` of chart to display one or the other ?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd3ahxp8/6/) demonstrating how I would do it.

Comment: What about if you just want to see a chart when you first click on `generate` Don't you need something else in the `v-if` ?

Comment: My code is similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/x7gbt1ee/. If you generate the first chart it is ok. But then if you change the `data` manually and reclick on `generate` the chart is not re-rerender. That's exactly my issue

Comment: @Leo it looks like you are using a different chart library. What chart library are you using?

Comment: I'm using `vue-chart.js`> In my example, instead of building only the data in `generateChart` I also build the new `labels`, `colors`, `label` of a set of data and so on. Why is that ? It is because I have options to change the scale let's say day / month / year

Comment: In my example, instead of building only the data in `generateChart` I also build the new `labels`, `colors`, `label` of a set of data and so on. Why is that ? It is because I have options to change the scale let's say day / month / year

Comment: The first time you click on `generate` it works good. But then imagine you change some options that are going to changes the `labels` and the `data` : we can simulate that by directly changing the value in the code the chart is not refreshed when clicking on `generate`

Comment: Example : Click on generate. Everything is good. Now replace `data` with `data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`  and click again on `generate `The chart will still use the old values

Comment: @Leo its the watcher. Set up appropriate watchers for the data you want to change.

Comment: I tried `this.$watch("chartData.datasets", this.showChart)`, `this.$watch("chartData", this.showChart)`. It does not work ... I'd like to re-rerender the chart if any properties change

Comment: . The watcher is triggered but the data used is still the same https://jsfiddle.net/eaae7cxh/

Comment: It is working on my site, but not on the jsfiddle. Thanks a lot @Bart for your time and your patience.

Comment: Now the former chart is not destroyed when generating a new one ... It will never ends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144693/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-leo).